# How to have MacOS finder show unmounted drives in sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, sidebar

I want to be able to always show my external drives on the sidebar even after they are unmounted so I can just click them to remount quickly.

I feel like this is possible through a terminal command and someone who is very experienced would know how. but asking none-the-less to see if anyone knows if it's possible and how. I could just go into disk utility each time i need to mount a drive later but after a while its get annoying, would be much easier if it just remained on my sidebar faded until mounted. any ideas or secrets to this.

Comment: An Alias to the drive might work. These would probably show in your Favorites section, rather than Locations.